# \tcboxmath not working as before in new version 5.0.0 of \tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Before I upgrade to the new version 5.0.0 of the excellent package \tcolorbox the following MWE was working perfectly well

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[theorems, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{boxrule=0.8pt, left=0.1cm, right=0.1cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm, sharp corners, breakable}

\begin{document}
Math Formula

\[\tcboxmath{Df(x)=-D_{1}g(f(x),x)^{-1}\circ D_{2}g(f(x),x)}\]

\end{document}
```

Now it produces an error saying I have to get rid of the Display Math.
What can I do?

The following MWE works without error (does not work with the previous version of \tcolorbox) but does not produce the correct formatting as Display Math (spacing before and after, centering, etc.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[theorems, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{boxrule=0.8pt, left=0.1cm, right=0.1cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm, sharp corners, breakable}

\begin{document}
Math Formula

\tcboxmath{Df(x)=-D_{1}g(f(x),x)^{-1}\circ D_{2}g(f(x),x)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It breaks because of the `\tcbset{breakable}`. Make a bug report here https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You mean if I get rid of this option, it will work fine again in display math environment right? I tried it and it actually does work again now. Thank you. Unfortunately some of my boxes behave less well at the bottom of pages, but it is a small price to pay in my opinion waiting for the bug correction. If you upgrade your comment to an answer status I will accept it!

Comment: This bug should be fixed with `version 5.0.1 (2021/12/20)`

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm perfect! everything works fine now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `\tcboxmath` in a display environment should not be breakable.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[theorems, breakable]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  left=0.1cm,
  right=0.1cm,
  top=0.1cm,
  bottom=0.1cm,
  sharp corners,
  breakable
}

\newcommand{\tcboxdisplaymath}[2][]{%
  \tcboxmath[breakable=false,#1]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
Math Formula
\[
\tcboxdisplaymath{Df(x)=-D_{1}g(f(x),x)^{-1}\circ D_{2}g(f(x),x)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as usual perfection made human! And the great advantage with this answer is that it will be easy to find/replace \tcboxmath by the new command.